# Function returning different value when another function is called before it

Tags: c, function

Title pretty much says it all. But I am running an character encoding function that shifts from a value based on an entered shift. This function runs fine by it's self but if a call a function above it then it returns "Ω" every time.

main.c

```
int main()
{
    assignment3();
    assignment5();
    return 0;    
}
```

---

equations.c

```
int assignment4(void)
{
    int res1=0, res2=0, res3=0;
    float parallel_resistance=0;

    printf("Please enter the resistance for three resistors: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&res1,&res2,&res3);// takes user input for 3 resistances
    parallel_resistance=calculate_parallel_resistance(res1,res2,res3);
    printf("The parallel resistance is: %.2lf\n\n",parallel_resistance);
    return 0;
}

int assignment5(void)
{
    char plaintext_character='\0',encoded_character='\0';
    int shift=0;
    printf("Please enter a character(a - z) and an integer: ");
    scanf("%c%d",&plaintext_character,&shift);//takes and assigns the user inputs to the                        variables
    encoded_character=preform_character_encoding(plaintext_character,shift);
    printf("The newly created character is now: %c\n\n",encoded_character);
    return 0;
}
```

These are from the header file which is included in the functions above

```
char preform_character_encoding(char plaintext_character,int shift_key)
{
    char encoded_character='\0';
    encoded_character=(plaintext_character-'a')+'A' - shift_key; // calculates the new character
    return encoded_character;
}

double calculate_volume_pyramid (double length, double width, double height)
{
    double volume=0,lwh=0;
    lwh=(double)(length*width*height); // calculates the volume using the inputs
    volume=lwh/3.0;
    return volume;
}
```

Comment: Which function is returning the incorrect value? Can you share your "working" code snippet, and the code when it is not working?

Comment: Use functional programming.

Comment: I don't see `assignment3()` function. Are you calling `assignment4()` instead of the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very careful when reading characters from the standard input: using `%c` format, because `scanf` would return any character that happens to be first in the buffer, including non-printable ones. In this case, it looks like `assignment4` leaves a dangling `\n` in the buffer. That is the character that `%c` gets inside `assignment5`.

You should add a loop for reading character, discarding whitespace and special characters, like this:

```
do (
    scanf("%c", &plaintext_character);
} while (c == ' ' || c == '\n');
scanf("%d", &shift);
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks you reminded me that my professor said to put a space infront of a %c.
`scanf(" %c%d", &plaintext_character,&shift)`

This is what I am using as we have not yet learned if, while and than statements.